# Soap-UI Mock Service(REST) not working after adding custom headers to response and creating a war file

Tags: web-services, rest, http-headers, mocking, soapui

I have added following custom headers to the response of a rest mock service in SOAP UI,

- Transfer-Encoding >>>> chunked
- Content-Type >>>> text/plain;charset=iso-8859-1

When I run the mock service from soapUI and test it by sending a request, I receive a response without any trouble.

But when I export a war file, then deploy the .war in tomcat 7 application server and try to test the mock service by sending the same request, I get the following message,

> Could not get any response This seems to be like an error connecting
>   to
>   http://localhost:8585/my-mocks-rest2/my-mock-service/.
>
> Why this might have happened: The server couldn't send a response:
>
> Ensure that the backend is working properly SSL connections are being
>   blocked: Fix this by importing SSL certificates in Chrome Cookies not
>   being sent: Use the Postman Interceptor extension Request timeout:
>   Change request timeout in Settings > General

[Screenshot of POSTMan response](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8IL7Mp42fnHcGh1QUE1ZjBEV00)

**Tomcat Log / catalina.log**

```
31-May-2016 14:41:11.638 INFO [localhost-startStop-13] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive C:\repo\apache-tomcat-8.0.24\webapps\newco-mocks-rest8.war
31-May-2016 14:41:16.204 INFO [localhost-startStop-13] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive C:\repo\apache-tomcat-8.0.24\webapps\newco-mocks-rest8.war has finished in 4,566 ms
31-May-2016 14:41:35.890 INFO [http-apr-8585-exec-39] com.eviware.soapui.mockaswar.MockAsWarServlet.initMockServiceParameters Init listeners
31-May-2016 14:41:35.892 INFO [http-apr-8585-exec-39] com.eviware.soapui.mockaswar.MockAsWarServlet.initMockServiceParameters Listeners not set! Reason : null
31-May-2016 14:41:35.894 INFO [http-apr-8585-exec-39] com.eviware.soapui.mockaswar.MockAsWarServlet.initMockServiceParameters Init actions
31-May-2016 14:41:35.895 INFO [http-apr-8585-exec-39] null.null Actions not set! Reason : null
31-May-2016 14:41:35.899 INFO [http-apr-8585-exec-39] null.null SoapUI core already exists, reusing existing one
31-May-2016 14:41:35.900 INFO [http-apr-8585-exec-39] null.null WebUI ENABLED
31-May-2016 14:41:35.906 INFO [http-apr-8585-exec-39] null.null Loading project
31-May-2016 14:41:36.233 INFO [http-apr-8585-exec-39] com.eviware.soapui.mockaswar.MockAsWarServlet.init Starting REST mock service [ISL023-srv-requestPaymentRefundMockService]
```

**localhost-access.log**

```
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2016:14:49:05 +0530] "PUT /newco-mocks-rest8/ISL023-srv-request-payment-refund/ HTTP/1.1" 200 267
```

Comment: Which version of soapui are you using?

Comment: Are you sure your service is deployed successfully? Looks your headers does not seems to be right, by the way.

Comment: what are all the options configured while exporting as war? also would you please edit your question and add tomact server.log portion

Comment: @Rao - Yeah am not getting a 404 Not found. Im getting "Could not get any response" as the response.

Comment: @Sumang - Following is a screenshot of my DeployAsAWar settings in SoapUI.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8IL7Mp42fnHMkJvMUx2NFFpSmM

Comment: You did not provided the tamcat server log for diagnosis, any way try selecting options and deploy again include actions and include listeners. Also please specify your mock dispatcher , further please add your tomacat server log

Comment: @Sumang - Sorry for not posting the catlina.log (tomcat server log) in my previous reply. I have now edited the question and added tomcat log.
I included actions and listeners as you explained and retried. But came up with the same response as earlier.

Comment: What kind of `dispatch` method are you using? And have you deployed it using tomcat web interface? Also what happens when you click the link that is part of your description (which is in the error)

Comment: Dispatch means how soapui respond to your request . Soapui has SCRIPT,RANDOM,SEQUENCE,QUERY_MATCH,XPATH as dispatch methods , double click on the mock operation you see a dispatch drop down, and let us know what is the dispatch you are using.

Comment: @Sumang - Thanks a lot !

Comment: @Rao- I'm using the "SEQUENCE" dispatch method. I deployed the .war file by copying it directly to apache-tomcat-8.0.24\webapps (Then again i tried deploying it using the tomcat web interface and didn't notice a difference in deployment). And while it deploys I could see the logs I have mentioned in the question. Further when I click the link it redirects to the URL(same as printed in the question) and displays an empty page. And when I opened the network tab in chrome and refreshed the page, it was noted that a 404 is getting returned.

Comment: Is the request  correct from postman, why because i have created a new mock and its working fine for me even with headers. please let us know , what is the payload for PUT and what did you select for body type? in postman  there are options form-data, x-www-form-urlencoded,raw and binary .. if its raw and what is the sub type ?

Comment: @Sumang- Could you please tell whether you created a .war file, deployed in tomcat and then got a response? 
In my end, Its an "application/xml" payload. And in postman i used Body type "raw" and the subtype "text". With these settings I get a response when the mock service is running on soap ui. But when i create a .war and deploy on tomcat it does not work with the same settings in postman.

Comment: In post man could you please change the body settings to raw + (application/xml) and try . FYI I have created war and deployed to tomcat and i am able to get response. Also please confirm in the mock response what is the "Content|Media Type" is set  in soapui mock response acceptable Content|Media Types are  "application/json","application/xml", "text/xml", "multipart/form-data","multipart/mixed"   in your post man the sub type must be either of the one.

Comment: @Sumang- Could you please tell me whether you get both "Content-Type →text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1" and "Transfer-Encoding →chunked" in postman response you received from tomcat? 
In soapUI I have set "application/xml" as Content | Media type. I tried the steps you explained and I'm getting the same result.  This is the soapUI mock service I'm currently working on.
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8IL7Mp42fnHR1dvMkxfUnBpSGM
(Appreciate if you can let me know whether you are able to deploy a .war file for this mock service and let me know whether it works for you)
Thank you !